# PHP: Building multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this:

```
Array(
  'level1' => 'someval',
  'level2' => 'someotherval',
  'level3' => 'thirdval'
)
```

I want to turn it into this:

```
Array(
  'someval' => Array(
    'someotherval' => Array(
      'thirdval' => 1
    )
  )
)
```

Obviously I could build the example above by hand but I don't know how many levels there will be. And this simple example might seem useless, but there are going to be more values, so there will be multiple arrays inside each of the levels.

Comment: Your questions is a little vague? what are you needing to store inside of the multi-dimensional array? What states to which level an array needs to be nested etc etc? Will that pattern continue or do will some levels contain multiple values?

Comment: Where does the value of `1` come from?

Comment: @Tim Cooper Sorry, that was a typo.

Answer (score 2):

This will do it

```
$array = array(
          'level1' => array(
             'level2' => array(
                 'level3' => 1
              )
           )
         );
```

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped part of my question. Please also see the last paragraph. I can easily build the array in the manner you demonstrated, but I don't know how many levels there will be, so I need to recursively loop through it or something similar.

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for, but you might research "pass by reference" and "recursive" function/method calls. That might help your understanding some.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this?

```
$levels = array_keys(Array(
  'level1' => 'someval',
  'level2' => 'someotherval',
  'level3' => 'thirdval'
));
$array = Array();
$aux = &$array;
foreach ($levels as $level => $value) {
   if ($aux == 1)
       $aux = array($value => 1);
   $aux = &$aux[$value];
}
var_dump($array);
```

Comment: Never tried using the "&" in PHP before. Looks good. Will try it :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on it:

```
function make_multi_level_array($arr) {
        if (count($arr) == 1) return array(array_pop($arr) => 1);
        else {
                $level_key = array_pop(array_reverse($arr));
                $sub_level = make_multi_level_array(
                        array_slice($arr,1,count($arr)-1)       
                );
                return array(
                        $level_key => $sub_level
                );
        }       

}
$arr = array(
   'level1' => 'someval',
   'level2' => 'someotherval',
   'level3' => 'thirdval',
);

var_dump(make_multi_level_array($arr));
```

Will output this:

```
array(1) {
  ["someval"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["someotherval"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["thirdval"]=>
      int(1)
    }
  }
}
```

Also tried other cases like below.

```
$arr = array(
  'level1' => 'someval',
  'level2' => 'someotherval',
  'level3' => 'thirdval',
  'level4' => 'fourthval'
);
```

Seems okay:

```
array(1) {
  ["someval"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["someotherval"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["thirdval"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["fourthval"]=>
        int(1)
      }
    }
  }
}
```